# Simple Situation! Weird Result! Spring prototype bean don't work, and every time I call getter or setter, the constructor was called

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I am learning Spring and using XML-way to create 2 beans instances of a POJO Class named "Notepad".
finally I got two instances:

```
n1 = Notepad@56dc1551,hashCode=267513570
n2 = Notepad@102cec62,hashCode=267513570
```

different toString @value, same hashCode!

Notepad.java

```
public class Notepad {
    private int a;
    public Notepad() {
        System.out.println("  constructor called. this="+this+" hashCode="+this.hashCode());
    }

    public int getA() {
        System.out.println("  this="+ this +" getA()，a="+a);
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        System.out.println("  this="+ this +" setA("+a+")");
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

scope-beans.xml

```
...
    <bean id="notepad" class="Notepad" scope="prototype">
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
    </bean>
...
```

Test.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:scoped-beans.xml")
public  class Test {
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    
    @Test
    public void testProxyScope() {
      System.out.println("containsBean(notepad)?"+context.containsBeanDefinition("notepad"));
      var n1 = context.getBean("notepad",Notepad.class);
      var n2 = context.getBean("notepad",Notepad.class);
      n1.setA(1);
      n2.setA(2);
      System.out.println("n1="+n1+" n1.a="+n1.getA());
      System.out.println("n2="+n2+" n2.a="+n2.getA());
      System.out.println("n1="+n1+",hashCode="+n1.hashCode());
      System.out.println("n2="+n2+",hashCode="+n2.hashCode());
      System.out.println("notepad1==notepad2? "+(n1==n2)); //???
      assertNotSame(n1, n2); //???
    }
}
```

[test result in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqdk5.png)

```
containsBean(notepad)?true
  constructor called. this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@4c2bb6e0 hashCode=1277933280
  this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@4c2bb6e0 setA(1)
  constructor called. this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@2dc9b0f5 hashCode=768192757
  this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@2dc9b0f5 setA(2)
  constructor called. this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@6531a794 hashCode=1697752980
  this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@6531a794 getA()，a=0
  constructor called. this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@3b5fad2d hashCode=996125997
n1=chp3.myapp.Notepad@3b5fad2d n1.a=0
  constructor called. this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@5e17553a hashCode=1578587450
  this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@5e17553a getA()，a=0
  constructor called. this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@3eb91815 hashCode=1052317717
n2=chp3.myapp.Notepad@3eb91815 n2.a=0
  constructor called. this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@56dc1551 hashCode=1457263953
n1=chp3.myapp.Notepad@56dc1551,hashCode=267513570
  constructor called. this=chp3.myapp.Notepad@102cec62 hashCode=271379554
n2=chp3.myapp.Notepad@102cec62,hashCode=267513570
notepad1==notepad2? true

java.lang.AssertionError: expected not same
```

I am expecting only create 2 instance, n1 != n2. but seems n1 n2 created multiple time, even when I do get and set!
And weirdly, n1 == n2 finally!
the code is very simple, I have no idea where the problem is...

Comment: The `<aop:scoped-proxy />` is the problem. It does exactly what you told it to do. Create a proxy for the given scope. Which means each time it is being used it will create an instance (due to the `scope="prototype"`. Remove it as you don't need it. Leave the `scope="prototype"` and remove the `<aop:scoped-proxy />` as you don't want a scoped proxy, you want that each time you call `getBean` get a fresh instance for use.

Comment: Are you running your container in some sort of multithreaded configuration? note the second constructor coming after the first set (should be before it)

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel
 no multithreaded configuration. Demo project, All default in IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<aop:scoped-proxy />` is the problem. It does exactly what you told it to do. Create a proxy for the given scope. Which means each time it is being used it will create an instance (due to the `scope="prototype"`.

Leave the `scope="prototype"` and remove the `<aop:scoped-proxy />` as you don't want a scoped proxy, you want that each time you call `getBean` get a fresh instance for use.

Scoped proxies are useful for web based scoped (like `request`, `session`). That way you can inject a reference and when needed it will actually delegate to the actual object in either the `request` or `session`. For `prototype` that means for each call to a method it would need to construct a new instance (which is what you see).

The call to `getBean` will actually return the proxy and not an actual instance of the object. That will only be created when needed, which is when calling the methods.

Comment: thank you! I konw few about aop:scoped-proxy.
so when print "this="+this+" hashCode="+this.hashCode(), the different toString @value is of each ClassInstance itself and hashCode is of proxy?

Comment: No it is the hashCode of a new instance. Basically each method call will lead to a new instance of the class.